# Quicker than $('#object:parent').parent().parent().parent()?

Tags: jquery

sometimes my box.attr('class') is undefined! Is their a quicker way of getting hold of box?

```
box=$('#eme:parent').parent().parent().parent();//define box
boxclass=box.attr('class');
boxnumber=boxclass.replace('b','');
```

by sometimes I mean nine times out of ten this works no problem...

Any clue?

Comment: how many boxes can there be, if only one, just use the box id, if not, then assign a class. unless you're not in control of the HTML output this would be the best way

Comment: humor--; $('@gdoron').append('<p>shudup</p>'); <div class="editme"><div id="b" class="b1"><div class="j"></div><div class="box"><div class="e1" id="e"><o></o><b>wooork!!</b><a></a><img class="nothing" src="R/n.png"><br></div></div></div><div id="b" class="b2"><div class="j"></div><div class="box"><div class="e2" id="e"><o></o><b></b><a></a><img class="nothing" src="R/n.png"><i id="eme">
<input id="eyoutube" type="text">
<input id="wwwe" type="text">
<input id="label" type="text">
<img id="es">
<img id="ec">
</i><br></div></div></div></div>

Answer (score 2):

```
box = $('#eme:parent').closest("[class]");
```

?

Comment: It looks like he seeking for the class, he doesn't have it.

Comment: set var I as the parent at the top level and give the item your looking for an id of #b... box=I.find($('#eme').parents('#b'));

Comment: Update: the problem happens when you go through the same function a second time (every time on second time!)